# Xtext: Cross-reference to other files works, but I can't access the EObject

Tags: import, xtext, cross-reference

This is my grammar:

```
A: field=[B]
B: C | D
```

The cross-reference works very well both when C/D sits in the same file and also when C/D sits in another file (using import).

The problem is with my function that gets Model (EObject, AST's root) as an input and extracts the C/D EObject.

When C/D sits in the same file, I can do something like this to get the C/D EObjects:

```
A a = ...
if (a.getField() instanceof C)
{
C c = (C)a.getField();
//do something with c
}
else if (a.getField() instanceof D)
{
D d = (D)a.getField();
//do something with d
}
```

However, when C/D sits in another file, **the cross-reference works** but the above doesn't work: a.getField() isn't null but it's also not an instance of C and not an instance of D.

Giving a model (that imports many other models), how can I access C/D that sits in other model?

**UPDATE**

This is my code to obtain the resource:

```
XtextResourceSetProvider rsp = (XtextResourceSetProvider)IResourceServiceProvider.Registry.INSTANCE.getResourceServiceProvider(uri).get(IResourceSetProvider.class);      

XtextResourceSet rs = (XtextResourceSet) rsp.get(project);

Resource r = rs.getResource(uri, true);
```

Comment: can you giv more context of "where" you are doing this?

Comment: I'm writing a new plugin that uses xtext. This plugin has a method that gets a file location and returns the corresponding EObject Model. Then I have another method in this plugin, which is described in the original question.

Comment: are you sure you use `org.eclipse.xtext.ui.resource.IResourceSetProvider.get(IProject)org.eclipse.xtext.ui.resource.IResourceSetProvider.get(IProject)`to obtain the resourceset and never ever call a StandaloneSetup in a eclipse context

Comment: Added my code for the resourceset in the original question. Is it fine?

Comment: yes that looks ok and should work. can you share a complete project sample thati can checkout and run?

Comment: http://www.filedropper.com/exampledsl After you download the zip and import the folders, generate the grammar, run the eclipse and import MyDSLExamples folder. After that go to ExampleDSL\ExampleDSL\MySamplePlugin\src\mysampleplugin\handlers\SampleHandler. Line 25 can have either "/MyDSLExamples/examples/importAnotherFile.mydsl" or "/MyDSLExamples/examples/NoImports.mydsl". Try to debug MySamplePlugin as an eclipse application and then click Sample Menu->Sample Command->OK.  Now iterateModel in class Main will work for NoImports but will fail for importAnotherFile. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks overcomplicated what you are doing

```
IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
IWorkspaceRoot root = workspace.getRoot();

IFile file = root.getFile(new Path(inputFilePath));
URI uri = URI.createPlatformResourceURI(file.getFullPath().toString(), true);
IProject project = file.getProject();

XtextResourceSetProvider rsp = (XtextResourceSetProvider) IResourceServiceProvider.Registry.INSTANCE
    .getResourceServiceProvider(uri)
    .get(IResourceSetProvider.class);
XtextResourceSet rs = (XtextResourceSet) rsp.get(project);

Resource r = rs.getResource(uri, true);
Model m = (Model) r.getContents().get(0);
```

Comment: Christian, exactly the same question but this time I want to run my plugin without running another eclipse. I saw this explanation https://typefox.io/how-and-why-use-xtext-without-the-ide but they use an injector to obtain the resource set. How can I use your answer so it would work in this case?

Comment: Standalone you have to add all resources to the resourceset manually